# Comparing row values in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, rank, window-functions

I have `Table1` with three columns:

```
 Key | Date   | Price
----------------------
 1   | 26-May | 2
 1   | 25-May | 2
 1   | 24-May | 2
 1   | 23 May | 3
 1   | 22 May | 4
 2   | 26-May | 2
 2   | 25-May | 2
 2   | 24-May | 2
 2   | 23 May | 3
 2   | 22 May | 4
```

I want to select the row where value 2 was last updated `(24-May)`. The Date was sorted using `RANK` function.
I am not able to get the desired results. Any help will be appreciated.

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT key, DATE, price,
               RANK() over (partition BY key order by DATE DESC) AS r2 
          FROM Table1 ORDER BY DATE DESC) temp;
```

Comment: where is the query you tried ?

Comment: SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT primary_key,
    DATE,
    price,
    RANK() over (partition BY primary_key order by DATE DESC) AS r2
  FROM Table1
  ORDER BY DATE DESC
  ) temp

Comment: I don't understand this, you want to return the row with pk = 3 and no other row? How come?

Comment: I mentioned that i want to retrieve the row where the value 2 was inserted last time and then it didn't change(I don't want to retrieve other rows as i don't want them )

Answer (score 1):

Another way of looking at the problem is that you want to find the most recent record with a price different from the last price.  Then you want the next record.

```
with lastprice as (
      select t.*
      from (select t.*
            from table1 t
            order by date desc
           ) t
      where rownum = 1
     )
select t.*
from (select t.*
      from table1 t
      where date > (select max(date)
                    from table1 t2
                    where t2.price <> (select price from lastprice)
                   )
     order by date asc
    ) t
where rownum = 1;
```

This query looks complicated.  But, it is structured so it can take advantage of indexes on `table1(date)`.  The subqueries are necessary in Oracle pre-12.  In the most recent version, you can use `fetch first 1 row only`.

EDIT:

Another solution is to use `lag()` and find the most recent time when the value changed:

```
select t1.*
from (select t1.*
      from (select t1.*,
                   lag(price) over (order by date) as prev_price
            from table1 t1
           ) t1
      where prev_price is null or prev_price <> price
      order by date desc
     ) t1
where rownum = 1;
```

Under many circumstances, I would expect the first version to have better performance, because the only heavy work is done in the innermost subquery to get the `max(date)`.  This verson has to calculate the `lag()` as well as doing the `order by`.  However, if performance is an issue, you should test on your data in your environment.

EDIT II:

My best guess is that you want this per `key`.  Your original question says nothing about `key`, but:

```
select t1.*
from (select t1.*,
             row_number() over (partition by key order by date desc) as seqnum
      from (select t1.*,
                   lag(price) over (partition by key order by date) as prev_price
            from table1 t1
           ) t1
      where prev_price is null or prev_price <> price
      order by date desc
     ) t1
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon for the reply.It is working well if i specify single key in where clause but failing for multiple keys.I have updated the question.And you have understood the problem correctly.

Comment: I don't understand the role that `key` is playing in your revised question.

Comment: The revised key is disturbing the results when i run the sql proposed by you.If all the keys are of same value, then it is working fine.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:-

```
SELECT Date FROM Table1
WHERE Price = 2
AND PrimaryKey = (SELECT MAX(PrimaryKey) FROM Table1
                  WHERE Price = 2)
```

Comment: This was an example...I can't hardcode in sql.There are other rows where value could be different

Answer (score -1):

This is very similar to the second option by Gordon Linoff but introduces a second windowed function row_number() to locate the most recent row that changed the price. This will work for all or a range of keys.

```
select
* 
from (
      select
            *
            , row_number() over(partition by Key order by [date] DESC) rn
      from (
            select
                *
                , NVL(lag(Price) over(partition by Key order by [date] DESC),0) prevPrice
            from table1
            where Key IN (1,2,3,4,5) -- as an example
           )
      where Price <> prevPrice
     )
where rn = 1
```

apologies but I haven't been able to test this at all.